# Adding Zeros Until Length of String = n

Tags: excel

I made the mistake a while back of stripping the leading zeros off of some data that I know has a length of n digits.  I have filtered for only those with less than n digits, and there are variable lengths.  Is there a way to use the REPLACE function or something else to account for the fact that I want to keep adding zeros to these filtered cells until the length becomes n?

EDIT: My current function is simply

```
=IF(LEN(K2)=n-1,CONCATENATE(0,K2),IF(LEN(K2)=n-2,CONCATENATE(0,0,K2),IF(LEN(K2)=n-3,CONCATENATE(0,0,0,K2),....,"")))
```

but I imagine there must be a more efficient formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eg:

```
=RIGHT("00000" & A1, 5)
```

Or:

```
=RIGHT(REPT("0",5) & A1, 5)
```

Adjust the `5` to the total padded length you want.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly the kind of concise solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If all the number in the column are the same length you could do custom formatting = 0000000 with the number of 0's you need.